# href not working when made into APK using Phonegap Build

Tags: android, html, cordova, apk, phonegap-build

I have created some very easy code in which I use multiple href function
like this.

```
<p> E-mailadres:<a href="mailto:frank.veelenturf@bwb-group.com">
frank.veelenturf@bwb-group.com</a><br/> />

Website: <a href="http://www.alucol.nl">www.alucol.nl</a></p>
```

(The first one should draft a mail and the second one should just open the browser and go to their site)

These work just fine when I run the code directly in on my computer using PhoneGap. However when I build an APK using PhoneGap Build the function doesn't  work on my phone. I was wondering if there was a fix to this.

Comment: You need to post your Content-Security-Policy

Comment: @Eric , I don't think I have one, could you be more specific? Because I did some research, and I couldn't find exactly what I am supposed to be with the CSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [whitelist plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist) for Cordova and use a Content Security Policy meta. This is a generic CSP to guide you.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' gap://ready file://* 'unsafe-inline' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; img-src *">
```